# Is data:image/png;base64 the only base64 encoding for the img tag?

Tags: javascript, android, image, base64, png

Been working in Java with images from the web encoded as base64 strings. I have only seen image/png format in img src tags i.e. `data:image/png;base64,{eNc0d3d_St!ng...}` I have not seen image/gif or image/jpg. I have looked on SO and read a little on base 64 encoding.

Furthermore, I strip off the `data:image/png;base64` part in Java (Android) when doing 
`Base64.decode(src, Base64.DEFAULT)` so it looks like there is no need for the png in that situation. In fact if I do not strip off this "header" then  `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns null.

So the question is, are there other formats other than png for image encoding on the web?

Comment: Most image (or other binary) file formats, like PNG, GIF or JPEG, contains a ("magic") identifier at the beginning of the file, that uniquely identifies the format. In this case, the `image/png` part is redundant, but this may not be the case for all possible formats that can be represented using the data URI scheme. So it does have a purpose. Also, keep in mind that the `;base64` part i *optional*, don't just blindly send the data to the Base64 decoder.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that answers some of my related questions on the topic. And generates a few new ones also. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes they are:**

data:image/gif

data:image/jpg

etc...

and not only for images:

data:text/html

The format is the follow

```
data:[<media type>][;charset=<character set>][;base64],<data>
```

Se here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

and

http://dataurl.net/#about

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use `gif`, `jpg` or any type of image that the browser reads. E.g:

```html
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

Comment: Maybe this is best as a separate question but: if I change image/png in the code above to image/gif, I get the same image. I expected to get maybe a corrupt image, but it seems that at least FF is rendering it the same regardless of the type of image declared

Comment: Right, once FF sees that the datastream is an image, it looks at the "magic number" to figure out which image type it is.

Answer (score 0):

async/await version

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const response = await axios.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Los_Colorines_4.jpg/320px-Los_Colorines_4.jpg", {
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
});
const base64 = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64').toString('base64');
const base64ImageUrl = `data:image/gif;base64,${base64}`
```

Demo: https://runkit.com/nickjanssen/axiosbase64image